# Срикошетить или отрикошетить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, выбор-слов, глаголы, приставка

*Брошенная в колесо палка может **от**рикошетить (**с**рикошетить).*
Глагол с какой приставкой предпочтительнее?

Comment: Предлог?!---------

Comment: Это приставка, конечно, Аллазар. Приставка — часть слова, а предлог отдельное (чаще всего короткое) слово.

Comment: Не «может (с, от?) рекошетить» от колеса, а точно так и будет.

Comment: Оба хуже. ----------

Comment: Я написал предлог?! Прошу прощения!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Рикоше́т** — полет какого-либо твердого тела после удара его под небольшим углом о какую-либо поверхность.

В словаре С. А. Кузнецова:
**отрикоше́тить**, -тит; *св.* Отлететь, отскочить рикошетом. *Камень отрикошетил от стены. Пуля отрикошетила.*

В словаре Т. Ф. Ефремовой:
**срикоше́тить**, *сов. неперех. **разг.*** Отлететь, отскочить рикошетом.

Палка, брошенная в колесо, может и отрИкошетить, и срИкошетить. Глагол с приставкой **от**- считается нейтральным, с приставкой **с-** — разговорным. Ваш выбор зависит только от контекста.

Стоит отметить, что рикошетит обычно пуля, граната, снаряд, дробь, камень, шайба, мяч, шар (в бильярде) — то, что очень быстро летит или движется. Палка же обычно просто отскакивает.
И правильно писать, конечно, надо так: р**и**кошет, р**и**кошетить, отр**и**кошетить, р**и**кошетный.